# Exclude some data from HTML table export

Tags: javascript, html, css, excel

I've a script for exporting data from an HTML table to excel. Now is my question how i can hide some data in the EXCEL file. Even when i try to use style="display:none;" on the TD he displays it in excel.

Greets,
Maik

Example:

```js
var tableToExcel = (function () {
            var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
                , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
                , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
                , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
            return function (table, name) {
                if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
                window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
            }
        })()
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>

<table id="test_table">
<tr><td>test1</td><td>Hide on Excel</td></tr>
<tr><td>test2</td><td></td></tr>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('test_table', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export Excel">
```

Comment: The "Export Excel" button doesn't do anything (FF 39.0.3)

Comment: That means he only works on Google Chrome.. That is strange, I thought the script was compatible with any browser. Does someone have a script that works with every browser? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Copy your table dom element, romove element you don't need and convert to excel.

Comment: Sorry but can you explain in more detail? I don't understand.